# C# AD users password expiry

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am using following code in form but I get an error

```
public DataTable Passwordexpire()
{
   PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

   UserPrincipal userTemplate = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   userTemplate.AdvancedSearchFilter.AccountExpirationDate(DateTime.Today.AddDays(3), MatchType.LessThanOrEquals);

   PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userTemplate);


  foreach (Principal foundPrincipal in searcher.FindAll())
  {
     UserPrincipal foundUser = (foundPrincipal as UserPrincipal);

     if (foundUser != null)
     {
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Columns.Add("AccountName");
       dt.Columns.Add("Name");
       dt.Columns.Add("Empolyee ID");
       dt.Columns.Add("Company");

       foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in Dsearch.FindAll())
       {
         DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
           dr[0] = (GetProperty(sResultSet, "samaccountname"));
           dr[1] = (GetProperty(sResultSet, "name"));
          dr[2] = (GetProperty(sResultSet, "ExtensionAttribute2"));
          dr[3] = (GetProperty(sResultSet, "Company"));
          dt.Rows.Add(dr);
       }
       return dt;
   }
}
```

The error is:

> *The type or namespace name User Principal could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
>   The type or namespace name Principal Searcher could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
>   The name 'MatchType' does not exist in the current context*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Reference to the `System.DirectoryServices` .Net DLL.

Then zaitsman's answer:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

Comment: Thx its worked. The name 'Dsearch' does not exist in the current context.  can u correck the code

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the `using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;` directive at the top of the .cs file in which this Passwordexpire method exists?

Comment: +1 for sportsmanship, you just beat me, but its only half the solution

Comment: Thx for reply, Iam using in form and its not there

Comment: Jeremy Thompson, yeah i kind of missed the reference half as it is even more obvious to me that you won't have access to something you haven't referenced, yet i occasionally find myself casting types in the extra classes where i forgot to mention the namespace

Comment: Thx its worked. The name 'Dsearch' does not exist in the current context.  can u correck the code

Comment: user113784, it seems you declared that object somewhere outside the bounds of the method. Verify that you are using the correct access modifier and that the object is instantiated if it is not static before calling the FindAll() method.